# Function using if statement in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I want to make a relatively simple function that takes a matrix or data frame and a single number as entries. Then, the function will replace the specific entry of the matrix or data frame with other numbers. My function is

```
spot_cell_type = function(estimated_cell, cell_type){
  estimated_cell = estimated_cell
  for (i in 1:nrow(estimated_cell)) {
   for (j in 1:ncol(estimated_cell)){
     if (estimated_cell[i,j]==cell_type){
     estimated_cell[i,j]==1
   } else if (estimated_cell[i,j]=NA){
     estimated_cell[i,j]==0
   } else {
     estimated_cell[i,j]==0
     }
   }
  }
  return(estimated_cell)
}
```

where estimated_cell is a matrix or dataframe form and cell_type is a non-negative integer. Why this function results error "Error in if (estimated_cell[i, j] == cell_type) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"? How to fix it?
This is an example of a data frame

```
estimated_cell = data.frame(A = c(0,1,2,3,3), B = c(2,1,3,2, 1), C = c(1,3,2,0, NA), D = c(3,1,2,3, NA))
colnames(estimated_cell) = c("0", "1", "2", "3")
```

Comment: Post some example data, and we can troubleshoot with you.

Comment: @Skaqqs Actually the error is inside the defined function itself, not when applied to the data yet. Anyway, I provide a simple data frame on the question.

Comment: The function is defined without an error on my machine. What does the input look like for `cell_type`?

Comment: If I define `cell_type <- "A"`, your function fails when `estimated_cell` value is `NA`. Try it yourself with the data you shared `if(estimated_cell[5,4]=="A"){}`

Comment: @Skaqqs Let's say NA is replaced with any number? How to make the function work? Regarding NA, I can add else if the argument for NA later, right? cell_type is just a number (I name cell type based on cluster number (0, 1, ..., 9)) so I will just use those numbers for this function. On my machine its error for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Like we discussed in the comments, your function can be defined, but it fails when you apply it to your data because your data has `NA`, which breaks your `if()` statement.

You could add an additional conditional to your loop that skips a value if it is `NA`, like you suggested. Note also that to reassign the value in the original dataframe, you'll want to use (for example) `estimated_cell[i,j] <- 0` instead of `estimated_cell[i,j]==0`.

Or you could use `ifelse()`:

```
my_func2 <- function(estimated_cell, cell_type){
  as.data.frame(ifelse(estimated_cell == cell_type | is.na(estimated_cell), 1, 0))
}

my_func2(estimated_cell, 3)
#>   X0 X1 X2 X3
#> 1  0  0  0  1
#> 2  0  0  1  0
#> 3  0  1  0  0
#> 4  1  0  0  1
#> 5  1  0  0  1
```

data:

```
estimated_cell = data.frame(
  "0" = c(0,1,2,3,3),
  "1" = c(2,1,3,2,1),
  "2" = c(1,3,2,0,88),
  "3" = c(3,1,2,3,NA))
```

Comment: why use `lapply` yet you have a dataframe? just do `+(estimated_cell == 3)`

Comment: @Skaqqs The function you suggested does not result in dataframe, does it? I want the dataframe output tho. Also, your function returns NA as well still. However, your suggestion estimated_cell[i,j] <- 0 instead of estimated_cell[i,j]==0 works. I still do not understand why estimated_cell[i,j]==0 does not work? It is the same as estimated_cell[i,j] <- 0 isn't it?

Comment: @Skaqqs I have edited my function using estimated_cell[i,j] <- cell_type instead of estimated_cell[i,j] <- cell_type, but instead of replacing any entries different from cell_type to 0, it replaces all entries with cell_type. Why is it the case?

Comment: @MKHuda, those symbols are different. `<-` assigns a new value to an object; `==` tests for equality. I updated my answer based on onyambu's suggestion. What behavior are you expecting when `estimated_cell` contains an `NA`?

Comment: @Skaqqs NA should be replaced by cell_type too actually. How to modify your function to consider NA? Your function is so simple, seems much better than my solution

Comment: @MKHuda, I updated my answer to also reassign NA values to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue like this

```
spot_cell_type = function(estimated_cell, cell_type){
estimated_cell = estimated_cell
for (i in 1:nrow(estimated_cell)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(estimated_cell)){
    if (!is.na(estimated_cell[i,j]) & estimated_cell[i,j]==cell_type){
      estimated_cell[i,j]<-cell_type
    } else if (is.na(estimated_cell[i,j])){
      estimated_cell[i,j]<- -1
    } else {
      estimated_cell[i,j]<- -1
    }
  }
}
return(estimated_cell)
}
```

It works perfect now.